# Is there a way to mention," If this.class1 is clicked, this.class2 should bs hidden/shown"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check the Coding below.

1. Following is the PHP coding which you guys obviously know.

Format :

[ block [ (image) (class-name="edit-block", id-name="type-one-edit") ] ]

...many blocks...

When the image is clicked, the class (edit-block) should be shown.

1. Likewise for all the other edit buttons, corresponding showable div's are shown.

The code for that is below and pretty long too.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(".edit-block").hide();

    $("#type-one-img").on('click', function() {
        $("#type-one-edit").show(1000);
        $("#type-two-edit").hide(1000);
        $("#type-three-edit").hide(1000); .......
    });

    $("#type-two-img").on('click', function() {
        $("#type-one-edit").hide(1000);
        $("#type-two-edit").show(1000);
        $("#type-three-edit").hide(1000); .......
    });

    $("#type-three-img").on('click', function() {
        $("#type-one-edit").hide(1000);
        $("#type-two-edit").hide(1000);
        $("#type-three-edit").show(1000); .......
    });

</script>
```

1. Question is, is there a way to make it in one step ?

Like,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(".edit-block").hide();                 //(all are hidden at first)

    $(".edit-img").on('click', function() {
        this.$("edit-block").show(1000);         //(show particular block)
    });

</script>
```

Kindly let me know if there is a solution.

Thank you !

;)

Comment: this is not a `php` question to start with.

Comment: Okay, @itachi. Do you know a solution for what I asked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you would like to do is something like this:

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/2yjUP/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="type-one-img"   class="btn" >image 1</div>
<div id="type-two-img"   class="btn" >image 2</div>
<div id="type-three-img" class="btn" >image 3</div>
<div id="type-four-img"  class="btn" >image 4</div>

<div id="type-one-edit"   class="edit">type-one-edit</div>
<div id="type-two-edit"   class="edit">type-two-edit</div>
<div id="type-three-edit" class="edit">type-three-edit</div>
<div id="type-four-edit"  class="edit">type-four-edit</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    var $target = $(this).next(".edit");
    $('.edit').not($target).hide('fast');
    $target.show('fast');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, Exactly. Let me try it in my code and update you, @naota.

Comment: I want output like this, http://jsfiddle.net/YZBs6/6/

But, can I do it without "data-no" ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, @naota.

I've updated the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/bRxqm/3/ 

It is working if I separate them too.

But I want it to work even when the number is increased.

Like, it now has 4. Because, the number of contents are not stable.

Can you make it without the ID ?

Comment: @ArunD Thanks. I hope you accept my answer if it is good enough :)

Comment: @ArunD, Thank you. To accept the answer, you can click the check mark of my answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Oh, Sorry. I'm new to this site, @naota. I've marked your answer as valid now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".edit-image").on('click', function () {
    $(".edit-block").hide(1000);
    $(this).siblings('.edit-block').show(1000);
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YZBs6/7/)

Comment: Nope. Not working, @Sreekesh !

Any other suggestions ?

Comment: @ArunD is the structure as in naota's fiddle? or each block consist of a img and div?

Comment: It is similar. But, I grouped the image and edit-block.

Whereas, he grouped all images first and blocks next.

Comment: I have a common class name (edit-image) for all the images (#type-one-img, #type-two-img, #type-three-img)..

So, shall I use,

$(".edit-image").on('click', function () {
    $("edit-block").hide(1000);
    $(this).next('.edit-block').show(1000);
});

Comment: Please wait, @Sreekesh Okky.

Comment: No! Not yet, @Sreekesh.

Comment: @ArunD Could you update the fiddle with the exact architecture of your html, and send me the updated fiddle

Comment: My architecture is exactly, this.

http://jsfiddle.net/bRxqm/6/

But, I want the code to automatically work even if the number increased. Like automatically increasing the ID or just working with the class name only.